# After Focus App's smart focus algorithms

Tags: ios, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to make image segmenting App in iOS. So I used `GrabCut` in OpenCV.

Then I looked into similar iOS apps and found After Focus. They are segmenting image fast with user's hint(foreground, background).

I wonder how to that way segment the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GrabCut` algorithm is basically derived from graph theory. The key aspect is to divide the image into two components:

- Foreground
- Background

Now the user draws many lines (in white and black) on the image to denote foreground and background. Each pixel on these lines is considered to be a **node** in a **graph**. There are **two additional ** nodes called **sink (background)** and **source (foreground)**

Each pixel on the lines drawn are connected to the *source* and *sink* with a particular weight.

*What are these weights?*:

- If a pixel (node) is marked as *background* by the user, it is connected to the *sink* node with a **higher** weight and to the *source* node with a **lower** weight.

  - If a pixel (node) is marked as *foreground* by the user, it is connected to the *source* node with a **higher** weight and to the *sink* node with a **lower** weight.

So every pixel (node) is connected to the *sink* and *source* node.

Every pixel (node) on the line drawn by the user is also connected to each other with a particular weight:

- Every pixel (node) within the foreground to connected to each other with an edge having a **higher** weight.
- Likewise, every pixel (node) within the background to connected to each other with an edge having a **higher** weight.
- But every pixel (node) within foreground is connected to another pixel (node) in the background with a **lower** weight and vice-versa.

Finally, `GrabCut` uses a parameter called `minimum_cut`. This parameter scans the entire image (graph) with pixels (nodes) connected to each other with edges of varying weight. This `minimum_cut` variable cuts along all the edges such that the total weight across the entire image is as minimal as possible.

Hence you get two separate images *foreground* and *background*.

For more info on the topic:

- Read [THIS DOCUMENTATION PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html)
- Also go through [THIS YOUTUBE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMGX8HXskKk&index=44&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A79y1StvUUqgyL-O0fZh2rs&t=2s)